# JVisualvm:How to take heap dump after the application terminated?

Tags: java, profiling, jvisualvm

I searched about it but didn't find any way to get heap dump after the application terminated.

From eclipse I am triggering a process of creating a new project using eclipse plugin development. At the code level I have two approach to create new project.
I want to compare both the approach.

I have used JVsualVm for analyzing data being generated in the process of creating new project generation.

As my process end with its execution I want to take heap dump of that running application.

But the problem is the after running process stops, it is being removed from the application view of the  JvisulaVM and I am not able to take heap dump of it.

So is there any way to take heap dump of stopped application from JVisualVm as I have still tab of that running application open but the application is removed from application view tree.

Comment: Nice question. Just for curiosity which type of application is this ?

Comment: It can be any application, but in my case it was a eclipse plugin development project which is to create android or blackberry project depending on the passed parameters. Actually I have two approaches to create project so just want to know which approach is better in term of heap and cpu usage.

Answer (score 2):

You could create it programmatically when the application ends:
https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/programmatically_dumping_heap_from_java
(http://web.archive.org/web/20170118001056/https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/programmatically_dumping_heap_from_java)

Okay, this is not exactly the end, but maybe enough for your needs.

Here's the code simplified from the above post:

```java
static void dumpHeap(String fileName, Boolean live) throws java.io.IOException {
    java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy(
            java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(),
            "com.sun.management:type=HotSpotDiagnostic",
            com.sun.management.HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.class
    ).dumpHeap(fileName, live);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's simply not possible. After the application terminates, it's memory, including the heap, is gone.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the tab for that application is still open and I can see the data also.So I think there should be some memory area where this data resides & may be we can create heap dump from that.

Answer (score 0):

Even I tried the same to get the heap details  from JVisualVM for the MBeans I have created.

I came to know once the application execution finishes, we cannot get back the details from it.

[Edited]

Ofcourse the tab remains in the JVisualVM they are not active to deal with.